# Issue with tab and navigation view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS app which is structured in this way:

One tab bar controller with 4 navigation controllers. Each navigation controller has its own view controller with a xib file.

The issue, is that **ONLY THE FIRST TIME**, when I push a new view into one of the navigation controllers, the new view doesn't appear at all. When I switch to another nav controller (touching one of tab bar's options) and then switch back to the first one, it works all the time.

The error I'm getting is when I come back is:

> [35731:70b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   .

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are presenting all your view controllers from the parent / top level view controller (the tab bar controller). I've had this a few times when presenting a view controller from one of the view controllers in the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewdidload` assign your first view controller to load when xib loads. Its the correct way to load first view controller to appear when nib loads.